# Granger Causality with multiple countries in Stata / R

Tags: r, time-series, stata, panel-data, plm

I have read several papers claiming to compare multiple entities (firms, countries, etc.) at the same time using Granger Causality. They usually group countries in east, west, north and south or urban / non urban (for example).

E.g. the public dataset by "Grunfeld" in the `plm` package has the following form:

| **firm** | year | inv | value | capital |

I have a similar dataset which I aim to explore using Granger Causality. My time variable is from 1990 to 2020.

| country_ID | country_type | year | sum | var_A | var_B ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2000 | 323 | 32 | 213 |
| 2 | 1 | 2000 | 13 | 0 | 7 |
| 3 | 2 | 2000 | 12 | 7 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 2000 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 2000 | 323 | 13 | 56 |

Stata does not return anything useful running this through, I suppose it's because of too many countries.

Is it even possible to take a subset of my dataset, say `country_type = 1` and run a Granger over the countries included? Or do I have to sum up all countries in `country_type` in order to run Granger?

One paper I looked into is (p.1310):
"The Causality Analysis between Transportation and Regional Development in City-level China" by He et al. (2019).

Comment: Whether Granger causality is better evaluated for single panels or makes more sense for pooled data seems to be a statistical question more suited for Cross Validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not write which of Stata's commands you use. If you have panel data, you may want to use the panel Granger (non-)causality test by Dumitrescu/Hurlin (2012), implemented in Stata's user contributed command `xtgcause` and in R's `plm` package as `pgrangertest`.

Below is an example of how to use `pgrangertest` with the Grunfeld dataset in R. The help page has references to the literature and some more information on how use more options (`?pgrangertest`):

```
## not meaningful, just to demonstrate usage
## H0: 'value' does not Granger cause 'inv' for all invididuals
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
pgrangertest(inv ~ value, data = Grunfeld)

# Panel Granger (Non-)Causality Test (Dumitrescu/Hurlin (2012))
#
# data:  inv ~ value
# Ztilde = 3.2896, p-value = 0.001003
# alternative hypothesis: Granger causality for at least one individual
```

Comment: yes, exactly. I have used both `xtgcause` and `pgrangertest`. But if I understand both codes corretly, they neglect my input `country_type = 1`. I tried splitting my dataset in different smaller subsets, but I don't think this how Granger is supposed to work.

Comment: If you want to test only a subset of your dataset, you would just feed the subset to the test commands, e.g., just countries of a specific type. The test result then tells you something about that subset.